# Proxy development in Android source code

Tags: android, proxy

I am trying to build a proxy for Android in the source and I need to set the proxy option under 'Settings'.

After researching in the internet, I found out that there is a 'settings.db' file in /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/ path, into which values are inserted into the table named 'system'. This works for the emulator (either by starting the emulator at runtime with parameters or by adb shell).

Question is, will the same approach as mentioned above, incorporated into a class file and built into source, be suitable for setting the proxy?

If at all, this method is feasible, will the browsers and the other apps which use internet, be able to detect the proxy?

Thanks in advance, for any help and suggestions.

P.S. I will be flashing the code to a dev phone.

Thanks,
Anu